# How to dynamically replace a button in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm making a to-do app. Basically, I want the screen to start with nothing but an add button at the top. As the user clicks on the button, the button slides down and the user can enter just enough characters that'll fit in one/two lines. The user can enter only 10-15 such tasks at a time, the button sliding down by the same distance each time. How do I do it? Here's the current xml code I've written:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.111" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/list_view" />
```

Also, I know the listview attributes are probably off. I'll try to fix them by googling but if you can help me with that right now, I'll appreciate that. Consider this a bonus question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here if you are using listview then simply add footer in the listview. Here is small snippet.

```
    TextView text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    text.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getApplicationContext(),R.color.text_color_light));
    text.setText("Block");
    text.setTextSize(Math.round(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.pad_top_bottom)-1));
    text.setPadding(pad+7,pad,pad,pad);
    text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            AlertMessage.newInstance(displayName,al,getApplicationContext()).show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"alert");
        }
    });
    listView.addFooterView(text);
```

It will definately work. Remove Button widget from xml and add it dynamically. (here in place of textView create button)